# Deleting all lines in text file with delphi

Tags: delphi

If I have already created text file, then I need to delete all line in text file for new fresh text. How we do it? Of course without deleting the text file first and then create a new one, just delete the text file content then add a new line text. To avoid error when a person in front of the monitor still opening that text file.

I'm using TextFile type, not TFileStream. Append, Rewrite, and closefile function to open file.

Just like

```
DeleteThisTextFileContent(ExtractFilePath(Application.Exename)+'log.txt');
```

Thanks !

Comment: http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=ReWrite

Comment: Your requirements are unclear. You want to empty the file, without deleting it, but without specifying how you're opening the file in the first place or how you're getting user input to that file. Please [edit] your question to be more specific. The obvious answer is to delete the file and then create a new empty file with the same name, but you've asked about doing it without deleting. Be more specific about your question, please.

Comment: Is it matter how to opening the file in the first place? If i already have the file that i created using notepad, is it matter to clear that text file using delphi?

Comment: Yes, it matters. If you're opening the file using the old style `File`, it's much different than if you're opening it with a modern `TFileStream`. You can obviously "clear" a file created with Notepad using Delphi, using a dozen different ways (including automating opening the file again with Notepad, selecting all the text, deleting it, and then saving the file with Notepad). The difference is in **what you're doing**, and you haven't specified that at all. As I asked, please [edit] your question and make it more clear. As it is now, your question is too vague to be answered.

Comment: Just to clarify: I can "clear a text file" at least five different ways without any effort (using `TStream`, `TStrings`, `DeleteFile/FileCreate`, `Rewrite`, and the WinAPI with `CreateProcess` and `SendMessage`); which one is appropriate for your use depends entirely on what you're doing before and after, and you haven't included that information in your question.

Comment: owh... that's matter then. Mmmm i was using old style TextFile just for simple log file, not TFileStream, append and rewrite. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using `AssignFile` to open the file (as your edit makes it appear to be), you can use `Rewrite`:

```
procedure DeleteThisFileContent(const FileToClear: string);
var 
  F: TextFile;
begin
  AssignFile(F, FileToClear);
  Rewrite(F); 
  CloseFile(F);
end;
```

Comment: Best answer !!! I just put it in the onCreate event form, so everytime form create, delete first the log file content. Thanks, Ken.

Comment: AFAIR this actually does and delete the file and create a new one.

To clear it one needs to `ReSet` it in r/w mode and then truncate its length.

Though indeed i cannot see the goal of the program doing that

Comment: @Arioch'The : your explanation looks like need more code than above code (need truncate its length and so on)

Comment: @Goggle just opening Delphi Help on `ReWrite` and friends would give you that `Truncate` function. Or you could just search for `Truncate` word in Delphi help.

Comment: @Arioch'The: Sorry, actually i'm not interesting read too many text about a method or something, because all of them sometimes too many talking about theory but never type the real code or sample about how to use it. I like delphibasics.co.uk (theory and sample is equal) and i hate embarcadero site (too many theory and lack of example). I don't want read the book manual first about how to drive a car, I just need somebody show me how to use a car first, then when I'm understand how to use it I will interesting to read the manual book to dig other feature of the car.

Comment: @gogglepink well, i hope i would not be on the road, when you would learn to drive a car by trial and error never reading any books or rules in advance. Theory may be boring, but it does have a reason to exist. You claimed you need to avoid deleting file, but you ended with the solution to delete the file. How does that fit in your mind ? That is the time when you have either "close your eyes" and press the accelerator and let it ride until it crash (maybe never). Or have to re-think you really need to avoid deleting. Or to copycat the code, that does avoid deleting. My answer has all 3 ways

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me topicstarter is somewhat confused with what he wants and what would happen in the system.

The claim is: *I need to delete ...content of ... file ... without deleting the file first and then creating a new one. To avoid error when a person in front of the monitor still opening that text file. Just delete the file content then add a new line text.*

However, some other answer uses `ReWrite` which - since the eldest Turbo Pascal 1.0 - does exactly what the  topicstarter claimed he wants to avoid - deleting the old file.

*If an external file with the same name already exists, it is deleted and a new empty file is created in its place.*
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Rewrite

---

Well, since erasing the file is okay for the topicstarter then i'd like to present few simpler ways to do it - few oneliners.

The one, using http://jcl.sf.net is

```
procedure DeleteThisFileContent(const FileToClear: TFileName);
begin
   JclStringList.SaveToFile(FileToClear);
end;
```

The one, using stock Delphi is

```
procedure DeleteThisFileContent(const FileToClear: TFileName);
begin
   TFileStream.Create( FileToClear, fmCreate ).Free;
end;
```

*`fmCreate`: Create a file with the given name. If a file with the given name exists, override the existing file and open it in write mode.*
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Classes.TFileStream.Create

That is doing the same delete-create sequence as `ReWrite` but requires less boilerplate.

*I believe the topicstarter can easily check file IO of his program using **Process Monitor** from `www.SysInternals.com` and check that those solutions, including some another answer there, are doing the same file delete action.*

---

One also can really discard the content of the file without deleting it first, but that requires explicit opening the *existing* file and explicit *discarding* its content. Modifying some another answer to avoid deleting, that would be

```
procedure DeleteThisFileContent(const FileToClear: TFileName);
var 
  F: File;
begin
  FileMode := 2;
  AssignFile(F, FileToClear );
  ReSet(F, 1); 
  Truncate(F);
  CloseFile(F);
end;
```

based on old Pascal functions

- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Seek
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Truncate
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Reset

---

Then *maybe* enters an issue of concurrent file access - that mentioned *error when a person in front of the monitor still opening that text file*.

1st of all, if the person reads a file in Notepad, that does not mean the file *IS OPEN* - that barely meant the file *WAS OPENED, READ AND CLOSED*. However if the person reads the file in Microsoft Word, then probably the file really *IS OPEN RIGHT NOW*. Since Windows makes little difference between the file and its name, in the last case the wished deleting of the file would be impossible using normal OS means.

But that is not all about *FILE SHARING*. The fact is that when some program opens the file it also specifies its demand on  *file sharing* constraints for it. Even if the programmer did not asked for it explicitly, it just should declare its intentions to OS using some defaults. And one can check it in Delphi RTL sources. If we think about the aforementioned case when *another user has the file opened in MS Word* then by default the file would be opened in *fmShareDenyWrite - Other applications can open the file for reading but not for writing.* mode.

And that means the very attempt to open the file in reading+writing mode (the call to `ReSet`) would fail, it would be kind of Access Violation on filesystem level. Same would happen if the topicstarter would try to `ReSet` for reading+writing a file from CD-ROM or from some read-only network share. Of cause the topicstarter still is able to alter `FileMode` and to do a read-only `ReSet` of the file. However... however then the file would be opened in read-only mode, and that means that removing the file content (calling `Truncate`) would no more be possible.

Well, what would happen if some exotic Viewer application would have the file open, would read it up to line 1234 (and have its "cursor" there) and then suddenly our program cuts off all the content and makes the file consist of just 12 short lines ? then suddenly Viewer would have an invalid location in the file and would no more be able to read form it without some kind of error recovery path, that would re-open the file or at least re-read it from the beginning. However if the Viewer's developer did not coded this specific error recovery code, then the Viewer would just crash.

So all in all, the topicstarter should have a think about his approach toward concurrent file access (sharing):

- Either ignore it, and hope that the program the user uses to read the file, closed that file long ago. Then he's free to delete the file and re-create it as some another answer suggests (or using one of those oneliners above). This would require thinking ahead and coding some plan what to do if it was not possible either to delete or to re-create the file.
- Or try to actually set the file length to zero, and let any other program, a user uses to read the file, recover from this or crash and die. This however also would require the "not allowed" code path.
- Or one may implement "round robin" scheme when the program keeps N last log files and always logs to a new one, and then tries to delete too old logs time to time. This way if delete failed it can just be logged and ignored. It would not prevent the application to log into a new file and the attempt to remove the locked outdated log would just be tried again a day or a week later.

Comment: The question specifically indicates it's a `TextFile`. From the very [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.Truncate) you chose to write a book about: "F is a file variable of any type **except a text file. Truncate does not work on text files.** F must be open." The majority of your answer is based on functionality that **does not work** with the specified file type, which is why **I did not use it**. So you can stop advising on all the ways my answer is wrong.

Comment: @KenWhite Ok, i corrected the code. And that code complies with "without deleting the text file" requirement, and the code which does not is explicitly and openly declared such, there is nothing swept under the carpet. I cannot know the reasons, why you chosen to ignore the explicitly spelled requirements - however strange they may seem - but that was your choice and it makes no sense to blame me for it.

Comment: The requirements include using TextFile, and I specifically mentioned all of the options you wrote about in a single **commment** 7 hours before you posted your answer (see the third comment to the original question, which mentions `TStream`, `TStrings`, `File`, and the WinAPI). The poster clarified to say "I'm using TextFile", and you posted that they should do everything except that, and to point out all the things you thought were wrong with my answer. I count at least four mentions of my name in your post, yet you chose to post an answer that is documented not to work at all.

Comment: @KenWhite About your comment i can only quote yourself: *This provides no information. "How do I drive a car?"* And that is not the point. *I'm using TextFile* and so? The API he requested was `procedure(const string)`. If you're so picky about `TextFile` then your answer is wrong twice - it should take `TextFile` as its parameter, not a filename. Really, instead of teaching the topicstarter you intentionally or not misled him into deleting the file while thinking he does not. And that alone outweights in my eyes all your jealousy towards my answer.

Comment: *Jealousy towards your answer*? Wow. You really are full of yourself, aren't you? What fantasy world do you live in where you think *I* would be jealous of *you*? What color is the sky on your planet? You seem to be the one with the issue - you couldn't keep yourself from mentioning my name four times in your answer. Who's jealous of whom?

Comment: @KenWhite You answer did not have other obvious easy to spot ID than the name, it was just practical. As you can see, i removed the name, since you had an issue with it. But you can count how many times i mentioned your name in the comments above. However with all those comments about me and my sky you just try to talk away from the issue: you caused topic starter to delete the file but to think he does not. OTOH, what should i expect from someone blaming the answer for having quoted the documentation? Have a nice weekend. I promise, i would not write your name anywhere during it.

Comment: Arioch, for me is this post (again) full of information talking about this and that (and of course about necessary JCL string list :-) That *modifying some another answer to avoid deleting* won't work. As @Ken already mentioned, `Truncate` does not work on text files (it's in the linked documentation). I'm not a downvoter, but if I were, this would get one...

Comment: @TLama -yest, that is a neat fluent-style collection of utilities in one place, why should i not like it ? Who cares about details of implementation ? The API is `procedure(const string)` - the fact that topicstarter uses `Textfile` somewhere in his program is not (and should not be misleadingly presented instead of) his requirement. If someone honestly would think it as requirement - then his procedure would take parameter of `Textfile` type - but it does not. However what ARE requirements is "do not delete file" and that requirement was covertly and knowingly violated.

Comment: Topicstarter's requirement is simple: **implement `procedure DeleteThisFileContent(const NameOfFileToClear: TFileName);` that would remove the file's content without deleting the file itself**. Does my implementation do clear content ? yes or no ? Does my implementation delete the file, yes or no? Does another implementation delete the file willfully violating the requirements, yes or no ? PS. i also rarely downvote answers especially where i participate. But tell: does willful and informed deceiving of topicstarter provide for downvoting? Maybe i should do it like some other person did, huh ?

Comment: @Arioch'The: Whoa using http://jcl.sf.net ? What is that? It looks more complicated using 'outside' delphi. I just need 'simple' delphi with 'simple' coding. So i can easily using any version of delphi.

Comment: @gogglepink 1) then use TFileStream oneliner. Since it is oneliner you'd not have to declare a separate procedure. 2) JCL is supported for many Delphi versions. Those that are not - are so outdated that can hardly be relevant. 3) avoiding using 3rd-party libraries - NIH syndrome - is leading to creating you'r own ad hoc partial replicas of those libraries. But then only your memory would be any documentation, and only you would be maintainer, compatibility warrant and bugs fixers. You may think that is "simple" but that is a kind of simplicity of using DOS Pascal instead of Delphi.